# Sort data received from API using Codable protocol based on date

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I'm parsing data from JSON using codable and using my completion handler to pass the data to its origin. However, before passing the caller, I would like to sort data and then send it. Below is my code

```
func getEmployeeData(for type: Employee, completion: @escaping (Result<EmployeesBase, APIError>) -> Void) {
    //set API endpoint for Employer
    let endpoint = type

    //Create Request with headers
    let request = endpoint.mutableRequest

    //get employee Data
    fetch(with: request, decode: { json -> EmployeesBase? in
        guard let jsonResponse = json as? EmployeesBase else { return  nil }
        return jsonResponse
    }, completion: completion) //Sort this completion by joiningDate
}

struct EmployeesBase: Codable {
    let employee: [Employee]
}

struct Employee: Codable {
  let name: String
  let empID: String
  let joiningDate: String
  let dept: String
}
```

I'm confused how I can sort this.

Comment: what's the expected json show `joiningDate` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
jsonResponse.employee.sort { $0.joiningDate <  $1.joiningDate }
```

---

```
struct EmployeesBase: Codable {
   var employee: [Employee] // make it var , as sort is mutating
}
```

---

```
let joiningDate: Date // parse this key as Date with correct format
```

---

Alter the decoder for this

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ" // change to your format
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
```